Best practices to include lots of tikz pictures in an overleaf project and avoiding compilation issues
I have a project on Overleaf with a lot of figures. These figures are created from csv files and use the tikzpicture environment. Here's an example:
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
               legend pos= outer north west,
                legend image post style={xscale=0.5},
                grid=both,
                width= \textwidth,
                height=5cm,
            ]
                \addplot[mark=none] table[x=X,y=Y,col sep=comma] {data/file1.csv};
                \addplot[color=green, mark=none] table[x=X,y=Y,col sep=comma] {data/file2.csv};
        \legend{first, second}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

I have around 15 of these figures. I'm also using the externalize library:

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzPlots/]


The problem is Overleaf often gives errors such as "Timed out" and doesn't produce any output. I have Overleaf premium, so free vs premium isn't the issue. I can solve this problem by commenting out all of the figures, then compiling, then uncommenting each figure one at a time and compiling. Then it works fine. But every time I insert a new figure there's the same old problem with Overleaf.
Does anyone know the best practice to avoid this issue? I read this post. The second answer (of making pdfs) is a pain on-the-fly resizing/formatting means having to regenerate the pdf. I'm not convinced that the first answer will actually solve this problem. Does anyone have any experience?

Overleaf suggests these solutions: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz%2C_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures%2C_so_I%27m_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F#Too_many_complex_graphics_to_externalize!

Best practice? IMHO: Use a local TeX installation (at least to generate the images as standalone images). If you are using overleaf free, you can also upgrade to an account with less limited compilation time.

I suggest to compile each tikz graph separately using standalone . See e.g. here for an example. Will also work on Overleaf. // Changes: compile changed tikz-file and main-document.

I personally find tikzexternalize to be very user-unfriendly in Overleaf. On local documents, I use memoize, which is phenomenal. One thing I might suggest would be to break up your document into several chapters, and then only import a few of them at a time with the import package. You could also use \include{} and \includeonly{}, though I prefer import. see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project

name the pictures. if you insert a picture anywhere but last, all pictures after that one will be recompiled because they are just named in sequential order. to avoid this, you can assign names to the pictures - either manually or automatically (takes some tweaking). then you will only have to compile the new picture when you add one, regardless where. when overleaf get one of the newer packages for externalisation, switch. those packages manage this stuff for you automatically. (at least, memoize certainly does.)
